# Is there any feature in Microsoft Viva to notify Teams users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is there any feature in Viva to notify Teams users  on Announcements or any other feature like posting important messages to Teams users.

Is there feature to send one notifications to Teams users using Microsoft Viva ?

Comment: You can get it started from [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-viva-blog/microsoft-viva-connections-helps-everyone-to-stay-engaged-and/ba-p/2107009)

Comment: I have used the PS to create the app and added it in teams . No difference with Teams App with Sharepoint URL configured as Tab. We were trying to explore if there is any other extensive feature to notify group of users in teams on the Announcements/Events in SharePoint Page !

Comment: Got it. Whenever i come across on the same, i will update the same here.

Comment: @Dev Thanks for your time