# Is there any feature in Microsoft Viva to send one way notifications to Teams users?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there a feature to send one-way notifications to Teams users using Microsoft Viva?

Or

Is there any feature in Viva to notify Teams users on Announcements or any other feature like posting important messages to Teams users?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any feature in Microsoft Viva to notify Teams users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66855147/is-there-any-feature-in-microsoft-viva-to-notify-teams-users)

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no capability for this in Viva itself, but it's possible in Teams using Proactive Messaging. Here is a sample I wrote for the PnP project, and it includes links to relevant docs at the bottom of the page for further reading: https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/master/samples/bot-proactive-messaging